# A double-sided lever and multiple forces

Tags: homework-and-exercises, forces

Assume a double-sided lever where the left arm has a length of `a` and the right arm has a length of `b + c`. Please refer to [this link](http://d.pr/i/exFm) for a picture.

`a`, `b`, `c` and `F` are known and `F1`, `F2` and `F3` are not. How do I find the `F1`, `F2` and `F3` forces?

**EDIT**:

The lever is weightless and it is in balance. However, it is also in motion and `F` is a force acting upon the lever as a whole - it's supposed to be some kind of sum of the `F1`, `F2` and `F3` forces - I'm just not certain if I could assume that `F = F1 + F2 + F3`. Anyway, the picture could be misleading - it **is not** acting upon the lever in addition to the other forces.

It feels kind of intuitive to me that I've got a sufficient amount of data. I just don't seem to be able to write down all the possible equations. In other words - how do you describe a double-sided lever with multiple forces applied using math?

Comment: Welcome to Physics! Please see [our homework policy](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/a/715/7433). We expect homework and homework-like problems to have some effort put into them, and deal with conceptual issues. If you edit your question to explain (1) What you have tried, (2) the concept you have trouble with, and (3) your level of understanding, I'll be happy to reopen this. (Flag this message for ♦ attention with a custom message, or reply to me in the comments with `@Manishearth` to notify me)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't given us enough information to solve the problem.  Is there any motion?  Do you know the weight of the board?  Anything else?

Typically, lever problems have two types of equations that can be useful.  The first is just the standard $\sum_i F_i = m\, a$.  Note that this is the *sum* of all the forces.  For example, in your picture, the sum of all forces is $F + F_1 + F_2 + F_3$.  If this is nonzero, the center of mass will accelerate.  In particular, if you really do have $F = F_1 + F_2 + F_3$, and if $F$ is nonzero, then that sum will be nonzero, and you will get acceleration.

The second type of equation is basically the same thing, except with torque: $\sum_i \tau_i = I\, \alpha$, where the $\tau_i$ are your torques, $I$ is the moment of inertia, and $\alpha$ is the angular acceleration.  Your equation $F_1 a = F_2 b + F_3 (b+c)$ can be rearranged as $F_1 a - F_2 b - F_3 (b+c) = 0$, which says that the total torque about the fulcrum is zero.  (Since $F$ is applied at the fulcrum, it does not apply any torque.)  You can sometimes get more than one equation out of this if you move your origin around.  For example, if you choose one end of the lever as the origin, $F$ could come into it.

From what you've told us, you have three unknowns (the $F_i$), and one or two equations.  That still leaves at least one unknown.  So you'll have to find something more in the physics to get another equation, so that you can solve for all three unknowns.

Comment: I updated the description.

Comment: I've updated my answer to outline the general method for solving lever problems, but you really still haven't given enough information.  Either you're not telling us relevant details or the question is ill posed.  Just count up the number of equations and the number of unknowns, and you'll see that there's at least one missing equation.

Comment: I think the three required equations could be: `F as the sum of the Fi forces`, `F1a = F2b + F3(b + c)` *as long as it's correct* and `some relation between the Fi forces, making use of a, b and c`. And, as I mentioned before, maybe I could substitute the `F2` and `F3` forces in order to find the value of the `F1` force? Sorry for the lack of clarity.

Comment: Okay, first, as I've said, `F as the sum of the Fi forces` means that the total force on the system is just 2F, so if this is not zero, the system will accelerate, which means that it will fly off the fulcrum.  I kind of doubt that this is what you want.

Comment: Second, `F1a = F2b + F3(b + c)` is the torque-balance equation, which is right if and only if the lever is not accelerating.  This is just something you have to tell us – whether it is or not.  You still haven't told us, which is why this question is vague and unanswered.

Comment: Third, you'll need some different physics – some detail that you haven't told us yet – to get the third equation.  I could make something up for you if you'd like, but I'd be changing your question by doing so.  You need to make your question more specific.

Comment: It is supposed to be nonzero. It's a small part of a bigger system. The `F` force is then countered with another force, but that's another problem.

Comment: Okay, now you've cut it down to just one equation, because you can't say F is the sum of the other forces.  You need two more equations to solve for your three unknowns.

Comment: To provide you with more details - this object is an airfoil and `F` is the lift force. `F1`, `F2` and `F3` are cutting forces, applied to the points (`-a`, `b`, `b + c` relatively to the *fulcrum*) where girders are located. I really don't know if this information is helpful, though.

Comment: That's the same amount of information as is contained in the picture.  Your problem is unsolvable as you've stated it.  Repeating yourself isn't helping.  You need to think about some other condition that you want this system to satisfy.  Are the forces equal maybe?

Comment: Not at all, unfortunately. That's basically all I've got. I have previously encountered a similar problem where I had just one force on each side of the lever. It was solvable because I could assume that `F = F1 + F2` (it was explicitly mentioned) and I also knew that `F1 * a = F2 * b`. But in this case I wasn't sure `F = F1 + F2 + F3` and `F1 * a = F2 * b + F3 * (b + c)`. But that doesn't help with the lack of the third equation, which I'm struggling to find. I was hoping I could extend the simpler problem to be any help with this one. That's also when the idea of substitution came to my mind